# sorting 32 bit numbers in 8086

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86-16

i wrote this code and think for it about 5 hours;
However i stuck in sorting part:
its begin to loop and never stop !
where did i wrong ???

IT SEEMS that the array didnt get the numbers correctly.
can any one help please ?

> ```
>     page 110,100
> Title 'decimal sorting'
>
> Data_here segment
> A DD Dup 20(?)
> msg1 DB 'Enter a maximum 6 digits number : ',0DH,0AH,'$'
> msg2 DB 0DH,0AH,'The sorted results are : ',0DH,0AH,'$'
>  Data_here Ends
>
>  Stack_here segment
>    DW 10 DUP(?)
>  Stack_here Ends
>
>  Code_here segment
> Assume CS:code_here , DS:Data_here ,SS:Stack_here
>   Main Proc near
> mov AX,Data_here
> mov DS,AX
> mov AX,Stack_here
> mov SS,AX
> Call decimal_input
> call sorting
> call decimal_output
> mov AH,4CH
> int 21H
> main Endp
>
>  decimal_input proc near
> PUSH A
> mov AH,09H
> Lea DX,msg1
> int 21H
> mov CH,20
>
>  next_number:
> mov BH,6
> mov DX,0
> mov si,4
>
>  next_digit:
> mov AH,07H
> int 21H
> CMP AL,0DH
> JNE check_digit
> CMP BH,6
> JE next_digit
> DEC CH
> JZ end
> mov DX,0DH
> mov AH,02H
> int 21H
> mov DX,0AH
> Int 21H
> jmp next_number  
>
> check_digit:
> cmp AL,30H
> JB next_digit
> cmp AL,39H
> JA next_digit
> mov AH,02H
> mov DL,AL
> int 21H
> SUB AL,30H
> SHL DX,4
> ADD DL,AL
> DEC SI
> JZ save
> DEC BH
> JNZ next_digit
> jmp remain
>
> save:
> mov A[DI],DX
> SHL A[DI],8
> add si,4
> DEC BH
> jmp next_digit
>
> remain:
> ADD byte ptr A[DI],DL
> mov DX,0DH
> mov AH,02H
> int 21H
> mov DX,0AH
> INT 21H
> INC DI
> DEC CH
> JNZ next_number
>
> end:
> pop A
> RET
>  decimal_input ENDp
>
>  sorting proc near 
>  Push A
> mov SI,DI                 
> check:                     
> mov AX,word ptr A[SI]
> mov BX,word ptr A[DI+2]
> CMP AX,BX
> JA change
> JE extra_check
> add SI,2
>
> continue:
> add DI,2
> CMP DI,38
> JA finish
> JB check
>
> extra_check:
> mov CX,word ptr A[DI+1]
> mov DX,word ptr A[DI+3] 
> cmp CX,DX
> JNA continue
> mov word ptr A[DI+1],DX
> mov word ptr A[DI+3],CX
> jmp continue
>
> change:
> xchg AX,BX
> mov CX,word ptr A[DI+1]
> mov DX,word ptr A[DI+3]
> xchg CX,DX
> mov word ptr A[DI],AX
> mov word ptr A[DI+1],CX
> mov word ptr A[DI+2],BX
> mov word ptr A[DI+3],DX
> jmp continue
>
> finish:
> Add sp,2
> cmp Sp,40
> JE ending
> mov DI,SP
> jmp check
> ending:
> POP A
> RET
> sorting ENDP
>
>  decimal_output proc near
>  PUSH A
>  mov AH,09H
>  lea DX,msg2
>  INT 21H
>
> next_no:
>  mov DL,0
>  mov AL,0
>  mov AH,0
> next:
>  CMP AL,0
>  JE next1
>  mov DL,byte ptr A[DI]
>  ADD DL,30H
>  mov AL,1
>  int 21H
>
>  next1:
>  inc DI
>  inc AH
>  cmp AH,8
>  JB next
>  CMP DI,80
>  JA THE_END
>  mov DX,0DH
>  mov AH,02H
>  int 21H
>  mov DX,0AH
>  int 21H
>  jmp next_no
>
>  THE_END:
>  pop A
>  RET
>  decimal_output ENDp
>
>   code_here Ends
>   END MAIN
> ```

Comment: If you get rid of at least blank lines you'll get more attention.

Comment: Use a debbuger and you will know. Programming is not just about writting code.

Comment: Now that you've removed blank lines - format the code so that it is readable, describe what you do (what kind of sorting you want to use and how) and how etc....

Comment: Where all the comments in the code are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be here

```
Add sp,2
cmp Sp,40
```

You are using `sp` as a loop counter, but you never initialize it. Additionaly I also don't understand why you are using `sp` in the first place. Of course it is theoretically possible, but then you would have to restore it before you return. When your proc returns it will screw up, because the stack pointer is corrupted. So you shouild use some other register or a memory variable (`bp` is not used in your code).

And I would strongly recommend to reformat your code, to make it more readable (when I looked at it I formatted it like this which makes it better readable):

```
sorting proc near 
    Push A
    mov SI,DI

check:                     
    mov AX,word ptr A[SI]
    mov BX,word ptr A[DI+2]
    CMP AX,BX
    JA change
    JE extra_check
    add SI,2

continue:
    add DI,2
    CMP DI,38
    JA finish
    JB check
 ...
```

Comment: i reformat the codes as you said,thank you ; im going to change that and see what will happen !!!